# react javascript css grid masonry responsive issue

Tags: css, reactjs, masonry

The responsive part of my code doesn't work well, as the browser width shrink, the height of image-list doesn't adjust properly. Why?

here is my imageList.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./imageList.css";
import ImageCard from "./imageCard";

const imageList = ({ images }) => {
  const renderList = images.map((image) => {
    return <ImageCard key={image.id} image={image} />;
  });

  return <div className="image-list">{renderList}</div>;
};

export default imageList;
```

here is my imageList.css

```css
.image-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 0px 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(1px, auto);
}

.image-list img {
    width: 250px;
    grid-row-end: span 2;
}
```

here is my imageCard.js

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ImageCard = ({ image }) => {
  const imageRef = useRef(null);
  const [spans, setSpans] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    imageRef.current.addEventListener("load", handleSpansChange);
  }, [spans]);

  const handleSpansChange = () => {
    const height = imageRef.current.clientHeight;
    const spans = Math.ceil(height) + 10;
    setSpans(spans);
    console.log(spans);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ gridRowEnd: `span ${spans}` }}>
      <img src={image.urls.regular} alt={image.description} ref={imageRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageCard;
```

Notes that ImageList is a component render in app.js file